# How to remove all entries that contain a value in a certain field? | MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, database

This is the structure I am working with:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("58dabf31fbd927071b51dhrc8"), "email" : "redacted",
>   "file_name" : "registration" }

I need to be able to remove all entries in the file_name field that contain "registration" -- does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete by regex matching the value.

```
{"file_name":{$regex:/registration/}}
```

See [mongodb regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for me info

In your case

```
db.collection.deleteMany({"file_name":{$regex:/(.*)?registration(.*)?/}});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate or give me an example?

Comment: Added example matching your request